# What component is used in the Twitter Bootstrap's docs for sidebar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm wondering what is the easiest way to build this kind of sidebar with Bootstrap 4.

> [image]

To me, it looks like a custom component they built for the docs page, not being included in the framework. I'm not sure if I'm right.

```
<ul class="nav bd-sidenav">
  <li class="active bd-sidenav-active">
    <a href="/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/">
      Introduction
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/">
      Download
    </a>
  </li>
   ...
</ul>
```

The closest I got was by creating something like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="w-100">
    <a href="#">
      Item 1
    </a>
  </li>
   ...
</ul>
```

But I think there should be a better way.

What is the right way to build such a sidebar/table of contents with Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple nav sidebar with content at the right:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <nav class="nav flex-column">
        <a class="p-1 nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        <a class="p-1 nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        <a class="p-1 nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        <a class="p-1 nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col bg-light">
      Here's your content! Added class bg-light for a light gray background.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Basically we're making a grid with the nav taking 1/4th `(3/12)` of the screen and the content using the rest of the screen.

If you want the nav to stack on smaller screens, you can replace `col-3` with **`col-sm-3`** for example. In this case the nav will stack under the `sm` breakpoint.

---

You can read more about vertical navs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#vertical), and the grid system [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is quite close, but there is too much padding. They didn't use `nav-link`, either.

Comment: See [this page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) to see how to adjust the padding. Don't remove the `nav-link` classes, they should be there. (See the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#vertical) code examples)